# Code Igniter 3 : Error fetching data with dots Field Name

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, codeigniter-3, field-names

I'm newbie in learning Codeigniter 3. I have some errors on my page.
The page is not showing any data  from the table.

This my 1st table structure :
[Pengguna (User) table :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phwzg.jpg)

This the 2nd Table :
[Karyawan (Employee) table :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icPBp.jpg)

And this my model file (User_model.php) :

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    function get_user()
    {
        $result = $this->db->query(
            "SELECT * FROM pengguna 
            LEFT JOIN karyawan ON karyawan.`id.emp` = pengguna.`id.emp`
            LEFT JOIN level ON level.`id.level` = pengguna.`id.level` 
            LEFT JOIN divisi ON divisi.`id.divisi` = pengguna.`id.divisi`");
        return $result;
        
    }
}
```

This my controller file (User.php) :

```
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('Auth');
        //$this->auth->cek_login();
        $this->load->model('User_model');
        //$this->User_model->get_user();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['is_login']) == TRUE)
        {
            $this->load->view("home/header"); 
            //$this->load->view('user/form_user');
            
            $data['pengguna'] = $this->User_model->get_user(); 
            $this->load->view('user/form_user',$data);
            //redirect('user');
            $this->load->view("home/footer.php");
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('login/form_login');
        }
    }
    
}
```

And last one is The View file on sub folder (`user/form_user.php`) :

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Username</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            $count = 0; 
            //foreach($pengguna->result() as $row[]) : $count++;
            foreach($pengguna->result() as $row) : $count++;
            {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td scope="row">
                        <?php echo $count; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->'id.level';?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
            }
            endforeach;
            ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

The result show empty data on field `['id.level']`

Thank you

I want to show my `['id.level']` field data

Answer (score 0):

**First, use the database field as [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). There is nothing wrong with using a dot. But still, it will give errors in the long run.**

---

To fix your issue, you can change the result formatting.

**In Model**

```
function get_user()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("");
    return $query->result_array(); # Add this
}
```

**In HTML**

```
<?php foreach($pengguna as $row) : $count++; ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['id.level']; ?></td>  # change this
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```